# python - socket not receiving data

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am trying to implement a RFC1350 on top of a UDP. So far all was smooth sending a file
from server to client worked like a charm i gave the method for receiving data to server and sending data to client but this direction is a no go.

Key Server code:

```
    def listen(self):
    while True:
        packet, address = self.serverSocket.recvfrom(512)

        mode = str(packet)[2:5]
        self.file = str(str(packet)[6:]).replace("'", "")

        if(mode == "RRQ"):
            self.sendResponse(address)
        else:
            self.receiveData()

def receiveData(self):
    data = open("new1.jpg", "wb")
    while True:
        packet, server = self.serverSocket.recvfrom(512)
        if packet.__len__() == 512:
            data.write(packet)
        else:
            data.write(packet)
            break;
```

Key Client code:

```
    def sendWRQ(self):
    request = 'WRQ-' + self.file
    self.clientSocket.sendto(str(request).encode(), (self.serverAddress, self.serverPort))
    self.sendData()

def sendData(self):
    with open(self.file, "rb") as data:
        while True:
            packet = data.read(512)
            if packet != b"":
                self.clientSocket.sendto(packet, (self.serverAddress, self.serverPort))
            else:
                self.clientSocket.sendto(packet, (self.serverAddress, self.serverPort))
                break
            time.sleep(0.0005)
```

1. Client sends WRQ packet whit a name of a file that will be the key of transfer
2. Server recog. the transfer type RRQ or WRQ in this instance and starts listening for
   transfer via receiveData().

Client terminates after sending sendWRQ() now a problem occurs on either Server or Client side in sendData or receiveData i get a file whit 0kB

All of the code:

- Server Class: http://www.copypastecode.com/181330/
- Client Class: http://www.copypastecode.com/181326/

Answer (score 0):

The method that the client informs the server the file is completed, is not correct.

In your code, when the file is completed, at the client side, you will call "sendto" to send an empty string, but this will actually do nothing; at the server side, you use condition "packet.**len**() == 512" to judge whether the file is completed, however, during the transfer process, if the server cpu is running faster than the transfer speed, you will get zero packet length frequently, but this does not indicate that the transfer is completed, maybe the next packet is just on the way.

My suggestion is to use a special command to indicate the end of transfer, and the server will only break the loop when that command is received.

Comment: packet has no attribute len()... and if it had it would return the same as __len__().

This however does not seem to be a problem. Since server to client transfer does work. Last packet is usually smaller than 512 indicating EOF and EOT.

Comment: don't know why __len__() becomes len() after formatted. I guess that the reason you got 0kB file is that the server breaks out loop when receiving packet with __len__()==0